# Query to read if row exists

Tags: vb.net, sql-server-2008

I need to know when and if a row exists and I want to use ExecuteReader right?

My code just to give idea of where I am going.

```
Const c_str_SELECT_SQL As String = "SELECT Fails FROM LoginAttacks WHERE IP = ?"

If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(strPointsDBConnectionString) Then
    objOLEConnection = New OleDbConnection(strPointsDBConnectionString)
    objOLEConnection.Open()
    objOLECommand = New OleDbCommand(c_str_SELECT_SQL, objOLEConnection)
    objIP = objOLECommand.Parameters.Add("@IP", OleDbType.Char)
    objIP.Value = Me.IPAddress

    ' Connect execute update query
    FailedCounts = CInt(objOLECommand.ExecuteScalar())

    If FailedCounts > 0 Then 'need to find way to tell if query worked/found row with ip
        FailedCounts = FailedCounts + 1
        'Did not fail assume worked so go use update function
        IPExist = True 'if not go use insert function
    End If
Else
    Throw New Exception(const_CONNECTION_STRING_ERROR)
End If
```

UPDATE:

I added:

```
objOLEDataReader = objOLECommand.ExecuteReader()

If objOLEDataReader.HasRows Then
    'Do While objOLEDataReader.Read()
    FailedCounts = CInt(objOLECommand.ExecuteScalar())
    FailedCounts = FailedCounts + 1
    'Did not fail assume worked so go use update function
    IPExist = True 'if not go use insert function
    'Loop
Else
    'none found
End If

objOLEDataReader.Close()
```

However, I don't seem to be going into the IF statement even with rows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oledb.oledbcommand.executescalar.aspx), `ExecuteScalar` will return `Nothing` if there was no data.  So you should just able to check for `Nothing` first to know if there were rows:

```
Dim FailedCountsObject As Object = objOLECommand.ExecuteScalar()

'need to find way to tell if query worked/found row with ip
If FailedCountsObject IsNot Nothing Then
    FailedCounts = CInt(FailedCountsObject)
    FailedCounts = FailedCounts + 1
    'Did not fail assume worked so go use update function
    IPExist = True 'if not go use insert function
End If
```